# How to click element in parent class using TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I want to typetext on textarea with parent class that marked on this following  img Snippet code
I want to use that class because id on textarea is dynamic element and will change every loaded. That's why I use parent class. I use

`let textArea = Selector('.block-card list-group-item text-card col-xs-12').find('textarea')

await t
    .typeText(textArea, 'Hai...')`

But got error:

```
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

> | Selector('.block-card list-group-item text-card col-xs-12')
  |   .find('textarea')
```

Here's the UI
UI.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

This might work

```
let textArea = Selector('.hwt-container').find('textarea').withAttribute('class','text-card-text')
```

Comment: I got error: The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

         | Selector('.hwt-backdrop')
       > |   .find('textarea')
         |   .withAttribute('class', 'text-card-text'). I edited the snippet code above, the textarea is not inside the .hwt-backdrop, that's why I want to use class on the snippet code (on rectangle 1st)

Comment: if it comes under hwt-container, this might work
Selector('.hwt-container').find('textarea').withAttribute('class','text-card-text')

Comment: if nothing worked, try 
Selector('.block-card').find('.list-group-item .form-group').find('div').find('.hwt-container').find('textarea')

Comment: When I use  Selector('.hwt-container').find('textarea').withAttribute('class','text-card-text'), I got error: The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree. Wehn I use Selector('.block-card').find('.list-group-item .form-group').find('div').find('.hwt-container').find('textarea'), I got error:  The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.

Comment: I think the parent div you are using is also dynamic.Try Selector('.list-group').find('.block-card').find('.list-group-item .form-group').find('div').find('.hwt-container').find('textarea')
If this also failed, please post your UI scenario here

Comment: I got error using you gave @VysakMohan : The element that matches the specified selector is not visible. The script:  let textArea = Selector('.list-group').find('.block-card').find('.list-group-item .form-group').find('div').find('.hwt-container').find('textarea')
    
    await t
    .typeText(textArea, 'Hai..', { replace: true})

Comment: Check your element is not inside an iframe. 
Also try waiting for the element like this.
`Selector('.list-group').find('.block-card').find('.list-group-item .form-group').find('div').find('.hwt-container').find('textarea');`
`await textArea.with({ visibilityCheck: true }).with({timeout: 10000});`
`await t .typeText(textArea, 'Hai..', { replace: true});`
Please post a screenshot of your UI

Comment: Still the same: The element that matches the specified selector is not visible. I posted the  UI on the post above

Comment: Do you checked whether its inside an iframe ?

Comment: No, it's not inside an iframe

Answer (score 1):

I would use an Xpath. something like : `//div[@class="block-card list-group-item text-card col-xs-12"]//textarea`

Comment: I use //div[@class="block-card list-group-item text-card col-xs-12"]//textarea still the  same, another error: An error occurred in Selector code:

      SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '//div[@class="hwt-backdrop"]//textarea' is not a valid
      selector.

Comment: I use another xpath, got error: The element that matches the specified selector is not visible. Is it correct if I use full Xpath then?